# Why is 'therefore' an adverb?

Tags: adverbs, comma-splices

> He is hungry, therefore he ate.

I do not understand how therefore is an adverb. It does not modify the verb hungry in this case, in any way. I understand it is a conjunctive adverb but it is still an adverb right?

Comment: It would modify *ate*. However, I've looked up *so*, and though it has a lot of uses, it is called a conjunction with examples where it is directly replaceable by *therefore*, so I don't understand why *therefore* can't be called a conjunction too.

Comment: A connective adjunct. Probably an adverb because it means "for this reason", which would typically have an adverbial meaning.

Comment: Note that many people would complain about a comma splice in that sentence. Whether or not you consider that sentence acceptable will likely affect whether or not you consider "therefore" a conjunction, adverb, or something else.

Answer (score 2):

Any word that modifies a verb by saying when, where, how or why the action took place is an adverb. Because it unites the adverbial clause with "He was hungry" it can be considered as a relative conjunction.

Comment: "therefore" can be considered as a relative conjunction

Answer (score 1):

"Therefore" was usually listed as an illative conjunction (indicating a conclusion), or sometimes as a conjunctive adverb (having the force both of an adverb and a conjunction).

In most books on logic, "therefore" is called simply an "illative conjunction." In some older grammar books, however, the term "conjunctive adverb" is still used.

"Hungry" is an adjective, not a verb; but it would seem that the adverbial character of "therefore" could be relating to the verb "ate", as in "He was hungry; he therefore ate."

Comment: Yes, a connective adjunct. Probably an adverb because it means "for this reason".